# Обнаружено нечисловое значение

Tags: php

Вроде код правильный, но пишет ошибку

```
$chislo = $data['day'].$data['month'].$data['year'].$data['predmet']['toch']['math'].$data['predmet']['toch']['informatika']; // делаем 11-значное  число для характеристики
    $fig = $chislo & 3;
    $color = (($chislo & 28) >> 2);
    $a = (($chislo & 16352) >> 5);
    $h = (($chislo & 8372224) >> 14);
    $w = (($chislo & 4286378688) >> 23);
```

Comment: какая ошибка мы должны угадать, да?

Comment: Обнаружено нечисловое значение

Comment: можно попробовать привести переменную к типу `$chislo = (int)$chislo;` но незнаю поможет ли это